# How i can keep value in p:inputMask after the focus lost

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with **InputMask** component in **Primefaces** v.5. My case: i enter a few characters in the field, but do not fill it completely. After that i move to another field. InputMask lost its focus and value has been erased. But why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `<p:inputMask>` reset its own value if the data entered is incomplete. You can change this behavior by setting the attribute `autoClear` to false.

Example:

`<p:inputMask id="date" autoClear="false" value="#{bean.date}" mask="99/99/9999"/>`

For more information, at page 253 of the [PrimeFace's v5 Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf) there's a complete guide of how the `<p:inputMask>` component should behave.

Comment: But this feature (autoClear) is not in the documentation and programmatically i cannot set this property.

Comment: It was added to 5.3.1 version. Thanks for your answer!